# PrimeVue with NuxtJs and Tailwind

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css, primevue

Good day, I tried to use Primevue in my project with tailwind. When I used tailwinde without Primevue, my styles works fine, but in the moment that I added the primevue library with the corresponding configuration (The config in the library documentation) all of my styles broken.

This is my tailwind.css
[tailwind.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cg53n.png)

And, this is my primevue config at the nuxt.config.ts
[nuxt.config.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmgBT.png)

Thank a lot

I tried removing the primevue library, and the styles works, also, I removed the tailwind.css and my own styles broken. I think that there are conflicts with tailwind library and primevue, but I don't know how to solved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

they use very similar classnames but the properties would not be 1:1, in short using primevue and tailwind mixed together probably is going to end in some re writes if you remove one.

Having primevue and primeflex installed should negate any need for tailwind.

If you really want to though you can look at https://tailwind.primevue.org/ which brings the two together.

any way you slice it you're going to be fixing up components that used the removed library.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PrimeVue in styled mode, CSS layer order is required for compatibility between primevue layer and Tailwind CSS utilities. This is mainly due to preflight mode which resets the browser styles of elements like buttons and forms. Please see this [link](https://primevue.org/nuxt/#layerorder) for a solution.

On the other hand, if you are on unstyled PrimeVue with [Tailwind presets](https://tailwind.primevue.org), then no configuration is required regarding layers.